# Javascript variable not working in php echo

Tags: javascript, php

My code :

```
<?php echo ' <script>var p=0;for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){p++;}alert("ques".p);? >
```

The value of p is displayed as 0.

Comment: Change to `alert("ques" + p)`, this is JS not PHP.

Comment: I hope the alert is for debugging!

Comment: just insert the javascript code in your html, what is the use of the php here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your php tag properly as well as the `<script>` tag like so:

```
<?php echo '<script>var p=0;for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){p++;}alert("ques" +p);</script>'; ?>
```

Also, change the `.` to a `+` as you are concatenating in javascript not PHP

Comment: You are the only one that also closes the script tag!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
<?php echo '<script>var p=0;for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){p++;}alert("ques" + p)'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in single quotes will be escaped, use quotation marks instead.

```
<?php echo "<script>var p=0;for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){p++;}alert('ques' +p);</script>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistakes in your code are,

1. Close your php tag properly - `?> instead of ? >`
2. Close the script tag in the end - `</script>`
3. Close the single quote you started with echo

The correct code would be

```
<?php echo '<script>var p=0;for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){ p++; } alert("ques" + p); </script>'; ?>
```